# How to convert 3/4 Character Integer to 24 Hour Time Format and combine with date ?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date, time

I have a doc Column of Date Time format, but it always leaves the time blank, and I have a time field which is an integer which represents hours and minutes (not including seconds). I would like to convert the time and add it to the date so that I can select `Max(datetime)` and return a single value.

Here is my [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8e22e).

The Data is stored as follows:

```
DocDate                 DocTime
2013-04-29 00:00:00.000 1416
2013-04-29 00:00:00.000 1027
2013-04-29 00:00:00.000 823
```

I'd like to convert it to:

```
DateTime
2013-04-29 14:16:00.000 
2013-04-29 10:27:00.000 
2013-04-29 08:23:00.000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some simple date arithmetics will do it;

```
SELECT DATEADD(mi, FLOOR(DocTime/100)*60 + DocTime%100, DocDate) FROM OPOR;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8e22e/31).

Comment: Thanks Joachim, Shortest answer yet. very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This should do:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            DATEADD(HOUR,DOCTIME/100,DOCDATE) DocDateHour,
            CAST(RIGHT(DOCTIME,2) AS INT) DocTimeOnly
    FROM OPOR
)
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE,DocTimeOnly,DocDateHour)
FROM CTE
```

[And here is the modified sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8e22e/37) for you to try.

Answer (score 1):

see [Sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8e22e/52)

```
select 
dateadd(hh, convert(int,left(doctime,len(doctime)-2)),
dateadd(mi, convert(int,right(doctime,2)) ,docdate))
from opor
```

Using [dateadd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to add the hours ( left one or two chars of doctime) and the minutes (right 2 chars of doctime) to the date.

Comment: Hi Ian, Thanks for your quick response. However it does not seem to be correct. You will see that my input data is primarily from the same date however your output has changed the date. I also see that the second result had in input time of 10:08 however the output only shows 00:08:00.00

Answer (score 1):

Just treat them both as datetimes and add together:

```
select  DocDate,
        DocTime,
        DocDate + stuff(right('0000'+cast(DocTime as varchar(4)), 4), 3, 0, ':')
from    OPOR
```

See example:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8e22e/54

Comment: Thanks Nathan, When I run this in SQL 2088 R2 I get the following error: Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: See fiddle example using your setup