# To bifurcate integer value into HH:MM format

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a column with integer datatype and it contains time duration in the below format. I want to bifurcate these values in HH and MM format as per the values in the below table:

```
Time      HH     MM 
---------------------
3         00     03
17        00     17
207       02     07
786       07     86
1234      12     34
```

Comment: This should already tell you to redesign. We have something like `TIME`, `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP`

Comment: [How to convert 3/4 Character Integer to 24 Hour Time Format and combine with date ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16307852/how-to-convert-3-4-character-integer-to-24-hour-time-format-and-combine-with-dat)

Comment: Just wondering why do you treat 100 minutes as 1 hour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with string concatenation:

```
select time / 100 as hh, mod(time, 100) as mm
```

If you want them as zero-padded strings:

```
select right('00' + cast(time / 100), 2) as hh,
       right('00' + mod(time, 100), 2) as mm
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #tt
  (
     tim INT
  )

INSERT INTO #tt
VALUES     (3 ),
            (17 ),
            (207),
            (786),
            (1234 )    

SELECT tim,
           left(right('0000'+cast(tim AS varchar(4)),4),2),
           right(right('0000'+cast(tim AS varchar(4)),4),2)
    FROM   #tt
```